# Why won't my image load?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, ioexception, javax.imageio

Edit for Answer: Ok, the problem was that my controller was null. Everything above works fine and loads properly. I was getting the nullpointerexception because I initialized my controller after I called it to get the image to paint. Thanks DoorKnob and SubOptimal for the help!

Question: I cant't for the life of me, figure out why my image won't load. I get IOExceptions no matter what I do.
Can someone give me a hint as to what I am doing incorrectly? I changed the actual image file to "insert file here" btw. Shouldn't make a difference

So in my gui class is the following code which should call the image and show it on the screen. It doesn't however. It simply outputs "couldn't load file". I'm assuming this error is because of the file not loading, but Im not sure and can't figure it out.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g = frame.getGraphics();
                try {
                    g.drawImage(controller.returnChar().returnImage(0), 100, 100, null);
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    System.out.println("couldnt load file");
                }
            }
```

Below is the imageloading class.

```
package SimplePlatformer;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class MyCharacter {
    //set the character sprite image here

    private BufferedImage charSprite;
    private int rows = 10;
    private int cols = 10;
    private BufferedImage[] charSpriteFrames = new BufferedImage[rows*cols];
    private int width = 32;
    private int height = 10;
    //for deciding which frames to show
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private boolean isWalking = true;
    private boolean isJumping = false;
    //for deciding which direction to show
    private boolean goingRight = true;
    //character location
    private int myX = 0;
    private int myY = 600;

    //constructor
    public MyCharacter() throws IOException {
        //set name
        //load the sprite image
        this.charSprite = ImageIO.read(new File("insert any image file here"));
        //set the frame locations in the array
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                charSpriteFrames[(i * cols) + j] = charSprite.getSubimage(
                        j * width,
                        i * height,
                        width,
                        height);
            }
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage returnImage(int x) {
        return charSpriteFrames[x];
    }
}
```

Below is the output I get in netbeans.

```
run:
java.lang.NullPointerException
couldnt load file
couldnt load file
    at SimplePlatformer.PlatformerGUI$3.paintComponent(PlatformerGUI.java:76)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5228)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1512)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1443)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1236)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1040)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1967)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3877)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:807)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:757)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:706)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1651)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SimplePlatformer.PlatformerGUI$3.paintComponent(PlatformerGUI.java:76)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5228)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1512)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1443)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1236)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1040)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1967)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3877)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:807)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:757)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:706)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1651)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Please post the full error that you get.

Comment: Edited the above text.

Comment: That's not helpful! That makes your question worse. We don't want more code, what is the actual error message?

Comment: Its a nullpointerexception. It is caught, and the text is outputted. If I get rid of the above try block and just try to run it, I get the following.

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at SimplePlatformer.PlatformerGUI$3.paintComponent(PlatformerGUI.java:75)

Comment: well, what's `e.printStackTrace()`?

Comment: Please just post the full error message!

Comment: I posted the output in netbeans above. I assume thats what you want. If not, I've no clue.

Comment: Hi,
based on the code on top. The NullPointerException is thrown because one of the following conditions is true
    - g == null
    - controller == null
    - returnChar() == null

Comment: SubOptimal! You are awesome. Doorknob! You are too! Thanks for the help guys. Controller was null. I didn't initialize it at the right place in the code. Thanks!

Comment: The line `g = frame.getGraphics();` in the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method is both unnecessary & suboptimal.  Remove it.  (I doubt it relates to the problem, but remove it anyway).

Comment: Thanks andrew. That actually resolved a flickering issue i was having... xP Thanks.